# Trying to change single value in array created with iteration changes multiple values. Why?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator

```
a = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
b = []
row = []
3.times { row << 0 }
3.times { b << row }

p a #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
p b #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
p a == b                         #=> true
p (a[1][1] = 1) == (b[1][1] = 1) #=> true

# and yet ...
a[1][1] = 1
b[1][1] = 1
p a #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
p b #=> [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

With this code, I'd expect the modified b to be the same as the modified a, but instead, the second element of each nested array is modified.

What am I missing? Why do `a[1][1] = 1` and `b[1][1] = 1` produce different results?

Comment: All `row`s reference the same object. Use `3.times { b << row.dup }`.

Comment: There's only one `row`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `3.times { b << row }` adds 3 references to the *same* array to `b`, so modifying it once changes it three times in the array.

Try updating this to `dup` the row as you push it into `b`, i.e. `3.times { b << row.dup }`.

(As I'm typing I'm seeing @mudasobwa beat me to it in a comment :) )

This approach will ensure `b` is filled with three unique arrays, rather than the same one three times.

If you're unsure, you can check the `object_id`, i.e. `b.map(&:object_id)` - at present, these will all be the same.

Comment: @SRack save for this question was asked here on SO a dozillion times and a lazy search would bring a dozens closed as duplicate answers.